# Can't send more than one byte via SPIDEV

Tags: linux, embedded

I am trying to access a NAND flash via spidev.
I want to send two bytes of data which is 0x9F 0x00 that asks for the device ID.
Whereas I can see 0x9f, I can't see the second byte, 0x00 on the oscilloscope.
Moreover, there is only 8 clock pulse triggered on the oscilloscope

It looks like cant send more than one byte, what could be wrong?

Here is my shortcode :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/spi/spidev.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *name;
    int fd;
    struct spi_ioc_transfer xfer;
    unsigned char buf_tx[32], buf_rx[32], *bp;
    int len, status;

    name = argv[1];
    fd = open(name, O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    //memset(&xfer, 0, sizeof(struct spi_ioc_transfer));
    memset(buf_tx, 0, sizeof buf_tx);
    memset(buf_rx, 0, sizeof buf_rx);
    len = sizeof buf_rx;


    printf("DBG#: 4\n");

/*
* Send a GetID command
*/
    buf_tx[0] = 0x9f;
    buf_tx[1] = 0x00;

    xfer.tx_buf = (unsigned long)buf_tx;
    xfer.len = 2;
    xfer.rx_buf = (unsigned long)buf_rx;
    xfer.speed_hz = 100000000;

    status = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), xfer);
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("SPI_IOC_MESSAGE");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("response(%d): ", status);
    for (bp = buf_rx; len; len--)
        printf("%02x ", *bp++);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
response(2): ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00... (32 times total)
```

Comment: Have you tested the setup with the `spidev_test.c` program?

Comment: @sawdust-When I try spidev_test, I got the error: "can't set spi mode: Device or resource busy" It's the line: ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_WR_MODE32, &mode) of spidev_test.c